# Same PWA for wordpress and angular parts of the web app

Tags: wordpress, angular, progressive-web-apps

My web app has the public marketing website built on wordpress (xyz.com) and the application on Angular (app.xyz.com). Angular app is being updated to a PWA. I want to know if I convert the Wordpress website as well to PWA and user add it as an app on the phone, is there way that the same PWA can be used open the application (angular) part of the website.

Comment: Better to use some plugins available for it. We have already converted few WordPress site into PWA.

Comment: Thanks, yes that I could figure out but my question is that the WordPress PWA and Angular PWA can work as same

Comment: Yes, it will work as same if you use the settings in a proper manner.

Comment: @tristup any specific directions on what settings are important for this. Is the app identifier in manifest enough?

Comment: Install Super PWA plugins which makes our sites PWA enabled, https://www[dot]realtybluefin[dot]com